# I can't use Vertical Scroll in a table and Horizontal Scroll in a container this table is in

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I'm creating a responsive table. This table should scroll vertically (keeping the thead), and the container which the table is inside should scroll horizontally, in order to enable the user to scroll the container if the screen is too small.

The problem I've got is that the table and its vertical scroll works perfectly, but for some reason I can not scroll the container horizontally, stead, the horizontal scroll appears by default in the end of the page (not in the end of the container, in the end of the page).

In a big screen:

[image]

In a small screen:

[image]

As you can see, the bar appears in the end of the page. I wanted it to appear inside the container. Something just like this:

[image]

```css
.container {
border: 1px solid #e0dddddc;
padding: 10px;
min-width: 1200px;
overflow-x: scroll;
}

.table-container {
border: 1px solid #e0dddddc;
width: 100%;
border-spacing: 0;
table-layout: fixed;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-container tbody {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
overflow-y: auto;
}

.table-container thead {
display: block;
width: 100%;
}

.table-container tbody tr {
transition: .3s ease;
}

.table-container tbody tr:hover {
background-color: #e0dddddc;
}

.table-container thead tr {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between;
width: 100%;
}

.table-container thead tr, .table-container tbody tr {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: baseline;
}

.table-container th, .table-container td {
padding: 5px;
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
}

.table-container th {
padding: 13px 5px;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
min-width: 180px;
}

.table-container td {
padding: 10px 5px;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
min-width: 180px;
}

/* Just for test */

.text-box {
margin-top: 10px;
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid #e0dddddc;
min-width: 180px;
}
```

```html
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./scrollable-table.css" />

  <div class="container">
<table class="table-container">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
      <th>Col 6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
      <td>row 1-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 2-0</td>
      <td>row 2-1</td>
      <td>row 2-2</td>
      <td>row 2-3</td>
      <td>row 2-4</td>
      <td>row 2-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 3-0</td>
      <td>row 3-1</td>
      <td>row 3-2</td>
      <td>row 3-3</td>
      <td>row 3-4</td>
      <td>row 3-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 4-0</td>
      <td>row 4-1</td>
      <td>row 4-2</td>
      <td>row 4-3</td>
      <td>row 4-4</td>
      <td>row 4-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 5-0</td>
      <td>row 5-1</td>
      <td>row 5-2</td>
      <td>row 5-3</td>
      <td>row 5-4</td>
      <td>row 5-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 6-0</td>
      <td>row 6-1</td>
      <td>row 6-2</td>
      <td>row 6-3</td>
      <td>row 6-4</td>
      <td>row 6-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
      <td>row 7-3</td>
      <td>row 7-4</td>
      <td>row 7-5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class='text-box'></div>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE**

I made some progress, and now the bar is appearing inside the container. But The element is broken now. It cannot reach the end of the page horizontally:

[image]

```css
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #e0dddddc;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.table-container {
    border: 1px solid #e0dddddc;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-container tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;

    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.table-container thead {
    display: block;
}

.table-container tbody tr {
    transition: .3s ease;
}

.table-container tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #e0dddddc;
}

.table-container thead tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.table-container thead tr, .table-container tbody tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: baseline;
}

.table-container th, .table-container td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}

.table-container th {
    padding: 13px 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    min-width: 180px;
}

.table-container td {
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    min-width: 180px;
}

/* Just for test */

.text-box {
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #e0dddddc;
    min-width: 180px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your .container has a `min-width` property set to 1200px.
Removing it and adding a `overflow-x` property should solve your problem.

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid #e0dddddc;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.table-container {
    border: 1px solid #e0dddddc;
    border-spacing: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-container tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.table-container thead {
    display: block;
}

.table-container tbody tr {
    transition: .3s ease;
}

.table-container tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #e0dddddc;
}

.table-container thead tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.table-container thead tr, .table-container tbody tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: baseline;
}

.table-container th, .table-container td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}

.table-container th {
    padding: 13px 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    min-width: 180px;
}

.table-container td {
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    min-width: 180px;
}

/* Just for test */

.text-box {
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #e0dddddc;
    min-width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table-container">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Col 1</th>
          <th>Col 2</th>
          <th>Col 3</th>
          <th>Col 4</th>
          <th>Col 5</th>
          <th>Col 6</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>row 1-0</td>
          <td>row 1-1</td>
          <td>row 1-2</td>
          <td>row 1-3</td>
          <td>row 1-4</td>
          <td>row 1-5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row 2-0</td>
          <td>row 2-1</td>
          <td>row 2-2</td>
          <td>row 2-3</td>
          <td>row 2-4</td>
          <td>row 2-5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row 3-0</td>
          <td>row 3-1</td>
          <td>row 3-2</td>
          <td>row 3-3</td>
          <td>row 3-4</td>
          <td>row 3-5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row 4-0</td>
          <td>row 4-1</td>
          <td>row 4-2</td>
          <td>row 4-3</td>
          <td>row 4-4</td>
          <td>row 4-5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row 5-0</td>
          <td>row 5-1</td>
          <td>row 5-2</td>
          <td>row 5-3</td>
          <td>row 5-4</td>
          <td>row 5-5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row 6-0</td>
          <td>row 6-1</td>
          <td>row 6-2</td>
          <td>row 6-3</td>
          <td>row 6-4</td>
          <td>row 6-5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row 7-0</td>
          <td>row 7-1</td>
          <td>row 7-2</td>
          <td>row 7-3</td>
          <td>row 7-4</td>
          <td>row 7-5</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class='text-box'></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello Rapahel. I think we're getting closer, it almost worked. Your CSS only worked when I added width: 100%; on .table-container and overflow-x: hidden; in .table-container tbody. But still the layout is broken, because the elements cannot reach the end of the page (horizontally), do you know why?

Comment: Take a look at the update I've put on the question.

Comment: You're right. I just updated the answer. I added a display:inline-block to the container so that the .text-box div takes the right size but it broke all. I just removed it but now, the text-box is not correctly sized

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how to size it properly without the use of javascript